# Samba Read-only shadow copies

Tags: samba, truenas, samba4, shadow-copies

We are currently running a FreeNAS 11.1-U6 machine (Which runs Samba 4.7.0) which we use for development. Since sometimes files get overwritten or deleted by accident before it gets committed in our VCS i have setup automatic snapshots every 15 minutes.

To make it easier for users to restore those files themselves instead of having to contact me i wanted to expose them using shadow copies, unfortunately this means that they can restore an entire directory to a previous state which I want to prevent.

My question is if there a way to disable the "Restore" option serverside to only allow the viewing of these copies?

Comment: I have the same issue. I would like to fully forbid the restore and let people only copy stuff from the shadow copies to e.g. their desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just use a *vfs recycle* samba module to set up a trashcan that the deleted files can be restored from.

Comment: Its a possibility, but if possible i'd prefer the shadow copy route since it allows for versioned overviews

Answer (score 0):

Define a GPO to gray out the "Restore" button in File Explorer.

Here is the GPO.

```
User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative templates 
 -> Window Components -> File Explorer -> Previous versions 
 -> Prevent restoring remote versions => Enabled
```